# Потерялось описание метки после назначения синонима

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, описание-метки

[После назначения синонима](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38893180#38893180) [компоновщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba) для метки [linker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker) и установки его как основной метки, потерялся текст описания.

Краткое описание сохранилось у меня в незакрытой вкладке:

> Linker - это инструментальная программа, которая производит компоновку («линковку»): принимает на вход один или несколько объектных файлов, файлов библиотек и собирает по ним исполнимый модуль.

Полное, наверное можно взять из архива интернета, но лучше вернуть всё это из базы SO.

Comment: В базу залезть не могу, применил описание.

Comment: А вот, нашёл: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/664284/revisions

Comment: А полного не нашёл, наверное его не было.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, [похоже на то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/664283/revisions) (внимание на даты создания первых ревизий).

Comment: @NickVolynkin следствие устранили. Осталось устранить причину такого поведения.