# Что происходит с описаниями меток-синонимов?

Tags: обсуждение, синонимы-меток, описание-метки

Был найден [артефакт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/702010/revisions), предположительно являющийся бывшим описанием метки [audio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio), которое улетело в никуда после синонимизации ее к [аудио](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be).

Т.е. создание синонимов может уничтожать описания меток? Как именно это работает? Заботятся ли участники об описаниях меток при нажатии кнопки синонимизации, чтобы ценный материал не исчез?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Может уничтожать, да. Прецедент был: [Потерялось описание метки после назначения синонима](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5621/176217)

Вероятно должно бы быть какое-то предупреждение о возможной потере описания метки. Ну и какой-то простой способ достучаться до скрытой информации после объединения.

Заботы появляются после выяснения факта потери, вероятно, требуются доработки механизма синонимизации.

Comment: Потерявшиеся описания есть в отдельном отделе админки, но без названий меток.

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо, что есть. Плохо, что без названий. Интересно, почему не добавили.